# Enemy Range Detection

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently making a Megaman game with very simple code. Right now, I am having some enemy detection problems.

Right now, I have a Rect around my enemies who are stored in a txt file and I want to check if the character's hitbox collides with the enemies Rect, which is his line of sight.

Basically, the collision detection is working, but when Megaman is in one enemy range, they all react as if Megaman were in their ranges as well

Here is the code that is important, the bolding is to help;

```
    *hunterrange=Rect(enemy[1]-100,enemy[2],400,40)
    enemy.append(hunterrange)
    if enemy[8].colliderect(hitbox):
        enemy[3]=0
        if modelx[X]<enemy[1]:
            enemy[4]=1
        elif modelx[X]>enemy[1]:
            enemy[4]=-1
        rangecheck=True
    else:
        rangecheck=False*

    if enemy[0]=="Hunter":            
        hunterbox=Rect(enemy[1],enemy[2],30,40)           


        if rangecheck==False:                
            if enemy[5]<enemy[1]<enemy[6] and enemspace<=0:
                enemspace=5
                enemy[3]=random.randint(-4,4)                    
                if enemy[3]>0:
                    enemmove=ERWALK
                    enemy[4]=-1
                elif enemy[3]<0:
                    enemmove=ELWALK
                    enemy[4]=1
                elif enemy[3]==0:
                    enemmove=EIDLE
            elif enemy[1]>=enemy[6]:
                enemmove=ELWALK
                enemy[1]=enemy[6]-5
            elif enemy[1]<=enemy[5]:
                enemmove=ERWALK
                enemy[1]=enemy[5]+5

       ***if rangecheck==True:                
            enemmove=ESHOOT***
```

Comment: Please cut this down to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, `global` and hardcoded indices (e.g. `enemy[7]`) are usually bad signs.

Comment: And why is anything stored in a text file ? Or is that irrelevant.

Comment: the reason why it is stored in a text file is so that i can specify where the every enemy is in the world. Basically, it is to make specific locations for every enemy.

Comment: And yes, the txt file string is irrelevant to the actual questions

Comment: What does each item in `enemy` represent? Especially: what is at indices 1, 3, 4 and 8?

Comment: The indicies are referring to the enemies X(1),Velocity X(3), direction(4), and range or line of sight(8). I had tried putting the line of sight as a seperate Rect from the list, but the same result happened